# unknown field "storage" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes

my pvc.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: database-disk
  labels:
    stage: production
    name: database
    app: mysql
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

running `kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml` in [microk8s](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s) got following error:

> error validating data:ValidationData(PersistentVolumeClaim):  unknown field "storage" in  io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistenVolumeClaim if choose to ignore these errors turn validation off with --validate=false

**Edit: storage indentation wrong when I copied text on my VM :( ,its working fine now**

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to specify the `volumeMode`. Add the `volumeMode` option and it should work.

Like this:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: database-disk
  labels:
    stage: production
    name: database
    app: mysql
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Comment: thanks for reply , i added Filesystem but still same error :( , without volumeMode settings its worked fine on GKE(google kube.. engine) . but with/without volumeMode it throwing error in microk8s :s

Comment: Hmm. weird. According to the docs it should work: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims

Comment: Try adding the `storageClassName` as @Nicolas Ben wrote.

Comment: OK, no problem.

Comment: `volumeMode: Filesystem` is anyway the default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a storageClass, define one as default to be used or specify in the claim the `storageClassName`.

I have defined this in GCloud:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  name: slow 
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```